# How to filter the view in Sharepoint, basing on user selected in Infopath form?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

I have a Infopath form, published to Sharepoint 2013, in which user selects exactly one person, using a people picker. Outside of form I have columns DisplayName and AccountID. I want user, who is viewing a list, to see only objects which are either modified by him, created by him, or if he was selected in form.

Trying to limit the view from browser-based view creator is most probably impossible, as neither of columns available outside are of type `User`. I then moved to Sharepoint Designer 2013, and dived into CAML. This did not help either.

How can I check, if currently logged user is the same user, as the one selected in form? I tried using CAML, but to no effect(last `FieldRef` is reference to column, in this example AccountID).

```
  <Where>
        <Or>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
                    <Value Type="Integer">
                        <UserID Type="Integer"/>
                    </Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Author"/>
                    <Value Type="Integer">
                        <UserID Type="Integer"/>
                    </Value>
                </Eq>   
            </Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="_638fe3aa_9161_4aa5_8bd1_862678d9fc06"/>
                <Value Type="Integer">
                        <UserID Type="Integer"/>
                </Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
    </Where>
```

If this can be achieved from code in Infopath, or in any other way, the answer will be as well accepted - I do not want exactly CAML based answer, I want any workable answer to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter in the view for each of the columns you would like to filter on set to [Me] should show logged in users only people picker values that are equal to themselves.

If the field in the form is a people picker then you must be storing the user data in a column somewhere unless you are discarding the data after processing it using a rule to update other fields.  If that is the case, I don't see why you can't keep the people picker data stored in a column that you don't display in the view. You do not have to base the filter off of a field you are actively displaying for it to work and you are already using the right type of control to get the data you need.

Created By and Modified By columns are always user values.

Comment: I can not check it right now, as I will go on a week off of work, but I am sure that People picker does not create a column of type `user`, but a collection of rows with three columns of type `string`.  When trying to show `selectedUser` outside, InfoPath shows, it will become a counter of selected values. I did not try it though, and will try as soon as I am back at work.

Comment: It is entirely possible to have an InfoPath people picker save to a person/group column in SharePoint, infact if you were to create a new list and add a person or group column and then edited the form in InfoPath this would be the default behavior.  When you look at user data in InfoPath it seems to be broken down into various text fields, but that is just how InfoPath handles the underlying object.

Comment: After checking it twice, I must say that column `Person`, after setting it as outside column, is of type int. And it is counter, as I mentioned before.

Comment: You are correct if it is an InfoPath form published to a SharePoint Forms library.  Why not use an InfoPath overlay on a SharePoint List instead?  That will give you the ability to do exactly what I said above while keeping the InfoPath interface.  I do not think you are going to be able to accomplish your task using native InfoPath as the [Me] filter is the only real way to filter SharePoint based on current user.  Your only other options I see would be to create a workflow that set a person or group field added to the Form Library based on the user id of the person selected in the form.